# Fourth term in the expansion of $(1-2x)^{3/2}$

Tags: exponentiation

Calculate the fourth term in the expansion of $(1-2x)^{3/2}$

I first tried to use binomial theorem , but of course fractions in combinations cannot be calculated (or is it that I don't know how to). And then is we add $r$ from $0$ to $<n$ by $1$, then there is only 1 term. So how to do it??

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the general binomial form. With this you will have that $$(1-2x)^{3/2}=1-\dfrac{(3/2)}{1!}(2x)+\dfrac{(3/2)(1/2)}{2!}(2x)^2-\dfrac{(3/2)(1/2)(-1/2)}{3!}(2x)^3+\dfrac{(3/2)(1/2)(-1/2)(-3/2)}{4!}(2x)^4+....$$

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Here you have to keep in mind that this works $|x|<0.5.$

Comment: Why is it only valid for $|x|<0.5$. and this expansion is infinitely on, so what about rational square roots whose expansion is not really never ending. So is there isn't any finite expansion or is it controversial or something??

Answer (score 0):

Note the general formula $$(x+y)^n = x^n+\frac{n}{1!}*x^{(n-1)}*y+\frac{n*(n-1)}{2!}*x^{(n-2)}*y^2+\frac{n*(n-1)*(n-2)}{3!}*x^{(n-3)}*y^3 + ...,$$ holds for fractional $n$ too.

Comment: @Sri what do you think?

Comment: Please see my comment on supermario's post. Thanks